# How do I make a poll request using Reactor Mono

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have to poll status from the external system until it turns ready. here's what I did.

```
checkStatus = webClient.get(...)
                       .bodyToMono(String.class)
                       .map(response -> Status.from(response));

pollUntilReady = checkStatus.filter(status -> status.isReady())
                            .switchIfEmpty(
                               Mono.error(new SystemStateNotReadyException())
                            .retryWhen(
                               Retry.fixedDelay(MAX_ATTEMPT, BACK_OFF)
                                    .filter(err -> err instanceOf SystemStateNotReadyException));
```

It works fine but I'm not expert in reactive programming so I'm not sure if this code is thread-safe or causing memory leak etc. Is it safe to do this or any better way recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet looks fine.

In case you want only a fixed delay independent of the query response time (i.e, if you want to send the query every x seconds, whatever time it takes for the previous request to complete) you can use `Flux.interval` combined with `takeUntil` or `any` to stop the flux as soon as you receive the right status.

By using interval instead of retry, you lose the ability to "back off", i.e. increase retry delay on the fly. However, interval will provide you with :

- a counter, to track the number of trials.
- the possibility to configure if you want to wait for a query to be completed before sending another (concatMap) or not (flatMap).
- Not sure, but you might gain performance because, with the interval approach, you don't need to create and catch exceptions.

Look at the following example :

```java
// Repeat every 100 ms
int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
    .concatMap(count -> fetchStatus
            .map(status -> new Report(count, status))
    )
    // Take operator add a limit on the total number of requests sent.
    // You can also use a timelapse instead of a maximum number of trials.
    .take(MAX_ATTEMPTS, true)
    // Take until sends all responses downstream until we get a true status,
    // included. You can replace it with `any` if you're only interested with the
    // successful signal. If using any, you can combine it with `switchIfEmpty`
    // to raise an error if no true status has been received after a given
    // number of trials.
    .takeUntil(pair -> pair.status)
    .timed()
    .subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Received: "+ value.get() + " after " + value.elapsedSinceSubscription().toMillis() + " ms"));
```

The above example prints:

```
Received: Report[count=0, status=false] after 157 ms
Received: Report[count=1, status=false] after 254 ms
Received: Report[count=2, status=false] after 352 ms
Received: Report[count=3, status=false] after 452 ms
Received: Report[count=4, status=true] after 552 ms
```

As we see, even if the query takes 50 ms to execute, it is triggered at fixed interval (every 100 milliseconds).